# Wireshark dissector errors Ubuntu

Tags: plugins, makefile, wireshark, ubuntu-16.04, wireshark-dissector

I have a wireshark plugin code which compiles and generates .so files perfectly under Ubuntu 16. This dissector was written for wireshark 1.6 and the plugin runs perfectly under wireshark 1.6.

However when I try to use this plugin for wireshark 2(or any wireshark version higher than 1.6) following errors show -

> Couldn't load module
>   /home/th89ct/.config/wireshark/plugins/plugin-1_0_0.so:
>   /home/th89ct/.config/wireshark/plugins/plugin-1_0_0.so: undefined
>   symbol: tvb_length
>
> Couldn't load module
>   /home/th89ct/.config/wireshark/plugins/plugin--1_0_0.so:
>   /home/th89ct/.config/wireshark/plugins/plugin--1_0_0.so: undefined
>   symbol: check_col

so I wanted to edit the code by replacing the methods - as after googling I've found that these methods do not belong to the new wireshark API.

but the problem is every time I edit the code - even by only putting a space in a blank space - following error appears -

> *gcc -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I/usr/include/wireshark -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -DINET6 -D_U_=**attribute**((unused)) -Wall -Wpointer-arith -g -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DXUSE_MTSAFE_API -fPIC -DPIC packet-ife.c -o packet-ife.o packet-ife.c:105:23: fatal error: epan/emem.h: No such
>   file or directory  #include 
>                          ^ compilation terminated. Makefile.linux:28: recipe for target 'packet-ife.o' failed make: *** [packet-ife.o] Error
>   1*

what should I do? I have no idea!!!! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem here is that emem was replaced with wmem starting with Wireshark 2.0.  You can read more about wmem in Wireshark's [README.wmem](https://code.wireshark.org/review/gitweb?p=wireshark.git;a=blob;f=doc/README.wmem;h=e00ad7c09b3c535cc769e612b1fc6a52dec00458;hb=HEAD) file.  Naturally, there are plenty of dissectors available in Wireshark's [epan/dissectors/](https://code.wireshark.org/review/gitweb?p=wireshark.git;a=tree;f=epan/dissectors;h=c3c72c88ac98bf35fa52313c26a0552a4b88893f;hb=HEAD) and [plugins/*/](https://code.wireshark.org/review/gitweb?p=wireshark.git;a=tree;f=plugins;h=e31dfa5340fa2b33feb4ce5dfa9b4e885de537c9;hb=HEAD) directories to serve as excellent examples to help you with the transition.